# Providing an Edit Button in Oracle Portal 10.1.4 in a Custom Search Portlet

Tags: oracleportal

I am using Oracle Portal 10.1.4 and I have a custom search portlet that is effectively doing a canned search that lists content that matches a certain category. I want administrators to be able to click an edit button beside a piece of content that shows up in the results list of the canned custom search portlet. (So each piece of content that comes back from the canned search has an edit link beside it that admins can click on).

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT having to write my own PL/SQL portlet (to replace the custom search portlet)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to manipulate the output of the standard custom search portlet is not possible and writing your own search portlet in PL/SQL or Java would be the way to go. The only other method I can think of would be to intercept the output of the portlet and augment it somehow, or use javascript to manipulate the DOM to add the required edit links.

Richard.